# Eclipse Run Display Different Every time

Tags: eclipse

I'm getting real pissed because of a problem that I know for a fact that isn't on my end! Every time I run my current project in Eclipse, the display is different every time!
I mean, I run it once and it shows only three of my components.
I run it again and it shows more.
I run it again and it shows three
etc..
What the hell is going on. This is the code I'm running in a main string args:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Survey");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("First name:");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel.add(label1, c);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Last name:");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(label2, c);

    JTextField text1 = new JTextField(10);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(text1, c);

    JTextField text2 = new JTextField(10);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(text2, c);

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("What is your favorite sport:");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(label3, c);

    String[] combobox = {"Basketball", "Soccor", "Other"};
    JComboBox cbx = new JComboBox(combobox);
    cbx.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(cbx, c);

    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Comments about yourself:");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    panel.add(label4, c);

    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(185, 100));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.gridheight = 5;
    panel.add(area, c);

    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 6;
    panel.add(submit, c);
```

Comment: When I run it and then resize the form, all of the components re-appear. How do i fix this..

Comment: I fixed the problem. I need to add frame.revalidate(); at the end of all the code.
I guess Java is the language where you need to do lame crap like that.

Answer (score 1):

Revalidate is not needed at all. **Make sure you properly create your components on EDT thread** and you'll have no such problems anymore. Check out the following article http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html